# Hydrology, operational rainfall-runoff models

Tags: data, hydrology, runoff

I am trying to collect information about operational rainfall-runoff models used around the world. I hope to build database with country outline with attached information what organization is covering operational rainfall-runoff models and what mathematical approach/models do they use.

Are there any other data sources regards surface(active) run-off?

Answer (score 1):

Russian hydrometeorological service prefers to use snow-runoff models (as the most of the russian rivers receive huge amounts of water during the spring snow melting). But I am sure that for several regions the models you are talking about are implemented too. A lot of them is are only for the inner usage; no info has been published overseas.

For instance:
Христофоров А., Круглова Г., Самборский Т. Стохастическая модель колебаний речного стока в паводочный период. — издательство МГУ Москва, 1998. — С. 145.

If you are still interested in this info, I'll hopefully try to collect more data.

Answer (score 1):

I know the Centre for Ecology & Hydrology (CEH) do quite a bit on this for the UK. Check their website here: www.CEH.ac.uk and more specifically have a browse around here: http://www.ceh.ac.uk/feh2/fehrefh.html etc...

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions

The Australians operate almost entirely on rainfall-driven models. Gets you around the snow melt modeling problem

South Africa has a well-developed (mainly) event rainfall rainfall runoff model based on US SCS methods. For starters check the works of Prof Roland Schulze, U. Natal, Pietermaitzburg.